# I need to locate Apps files to make them available to Unity Launch Folders

Tags: directory, desktop-apps

I have only been able to do it for an app I downloaded its Debian file for. Of course I chose where to install it, hence I knew where to find it. I simply drag and dropped to a drawer window of [Unity Launch Folders](http://unity-folders.exceptionfound.com/).

But of course, for all the other apps it's a whole different story.

Any pointers please?

Thanks guys,

DPC

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel silly! 
The answer is in Anton's YouTube video!
Basically you find the app you want to add with the Super key, with the Search tool at the top of the Unity panel. Then just drag the app icon found right into the Unity Launch Folders drawer you previously created. And take it from there.